# tkinter - How to set one Checkbutton opposite of other?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to set the value of one checkbox to always be the opposite of the other using tkinter (python3.5). I want it to be so that when ever the user click on one of the Checkbuttons, the other button is always changed to the opposite value.

What am I doing wrong? I cant work it out.

```
from tkinter import *


def opposite(buttonA):
    print("running Opposite")
    if buttonA.get() == 0:
       buttonB.set(1)
    elif buttonA.get() == 1:
       buttonB.set(0)


root = Tk()

buttonA=IntVar()
buttonA.set(1)
buttonAchk = Checkbutton(root, variable=buttonA)
buttonAchk.pack()

buttonAlabel = Label(root, width=30, text="Button A")
buttonAlabel.pack()

buttonB=IntVar()
buttonB.set(0)
buttonBCheck = Checkbutton(root, variable=opposite(buttonA))
buttonBCheck.pack()

buttonBlabel = Label(root, width=30, text="Button B")
buttonBlabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You probably want a [radiobutton](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/radiobutton.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use, `Radiobutton` instead?

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

buttonA=IntVar()

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Button A", width = 30,  variable=buttonA, value=1)
R1.pack()

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Button B", width = 30, variable=buttonA, value=0)
R2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```